# UWP How to make textbox with auto-complete which moves with cursor?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I need to make a textbox which gives users auto-complete hint near the cursor as they type (the width is large).

Is there a control from 3d party devs or a robust idea on how to write it ?

Comment: Do you want the [`AutoSuggestBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/auto-suggest-box)? It represents a text control that makes suggestions to users as they type. The app is notified when text has been changed by the user and is responsible for providing relevant suggestions for this control to display.

Comment: I think the key point is the "near the cursor as they type", which none of the standard autocomplete-enabled controls I know of, can do

Comment: yes. imagine the text box is 2000px wide and your are typing in the end of it, the "regular" suggestion isn't working very well.. also it could be 2 or 3 lines.. is there an open source code for AutoSuggestBox somewhere?